# Remover elementos duplicados de um array em um map

Tags: javascript, html, react

Bom dia, tudo bem? EU estou usando React JS para fazer uma aplicação de teste e tenho um array de dados que é o seguinte:

```
const data: any[] = [
    {
      propose: '1',
      cpf: '000.000.000-00',
      status: 'Oi',
      store_type: 'Teste',
      store: 'teste',
      amount: 'R$ 5.000,00',
      sale_date: '10/10/10',
      seller: 'Alan',
      interest_rate: '0.89%',
      uf: 'SP',
      sales_network: 'LOJA 3'
    },
    {
      propose: '2',
      cpf: '000.000.000-00',
      status: 'Mobily',
      store_type: 'Teste',
      store: 'teste',
      amount: 'R$ 5.000,00',
      sale_date: '10/10/10',
      seller: 'Alan',
      interest_rate: '0.89%',
      uf: 'MG',
      sales_network: 'LOJA 2'
    },
    {
      propose: '3',
      cpf: '000.000.000-00',
      status: 'Testando',
      store_type: 'Teste',
      store: 'teste',
      amount: 'R$ 5.000,00',
      sale_date: '10/10/10',
      seller: 'Marcos',
      interest_rate: '0.80%',
      uf: 'MG',
      sales_network: 'LOJA 1'
    },
    {
      propose: '4',
      cpf: '000.000.000-00',
      status: 'Testando',
      store_type: 'Teste',
      store: 'teste',
      amount: 'R$ 5.000,00',
      sale_date: '10/10/10',
      seller: 'Vinicius',
      interest_rate: '0.80%',
      uf: 'MG',
      sales_network: 'LOJA 1'
    },
  ]
```

Eu estou tentando fazer um filtro de UF desse map e exibir checkbox para o usuário selecionar quais UF's ele quer filtrar na minha tabela. Pra fazer esse map eu estou fazendo o seguinte:

```
 {data.map((item) => {
          return (
            <>
              <Checkbox
                onChange={(e) => handleCheckboxChange(e, property)}
                id={item[property]}
                label={item[property]}
                name={item[property]}
                defaultValue={item[property]}
              />
            </>
          )
        })}
```

Porém o resultado desse map está sendo esse aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de filtrar os UF's para que em caso de repetição (como acontece com MG) ele aparecesse somente uma vez, como posso fazer isso?

Se alguem puder me ajudar, ficaria agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: A solução pode apresentar um erro no TypeScript, dando algumas pesquisadas sobre o assunto, parece ser algo que acontece quando usamos o *spread* no `Set()` e com o target ES5 no *tsconfig*.

Há possiveis soluções para alerta do TypeScript:

- Adicionar `downlevelIteration:true`;
- Mudando o Target no *tsconfig* pra ES6;
- Dando um "cast" no `new Set()` para que o *spread* se comporte como um *Array*: `[...Array.from(new Set(UFList))]`

[Discussão relacionada com esse update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464504/using-spread-syntax-and-new-set-with-typescript)

---

O `map` por principio retorna um novo *array* em base de cada posição de outro *array*.

Para gerar um *array* reduzido a partir de outro, um `filter` poderia se encaixar melhor, porém no seu cenário uma sugestão seria fazer uma formatação prévia antes de renderizar seus dados.
Você pode ao recebê-los armazenar em um array separado somente os UF's.

E após isso eliminar os duplicados através do construtor do
[Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) em conjunto de um *spread* `...`

Com isso recomendaria guardar essa lista dentro de um estado após a formatação.

Segue exemplo:

```js
const data: any[] = [
    {
      propose: '1',
      cpf: '000.000.000-00',
      status: 'Oi',
      store_type: 'Teste',
      store: 'teste',
      amount: 'R$ 5.000,00',
      sale_date: '10/10/10',
      seller: 'Alan',
      interest_rate: '0.89%',
      uf: 'SP',
      sales_network: 'LOJA 3'
    },
    {
      propose: '2',
      cpf: '000.000.000-00',
      status: 'Mobily',
      store_type: 'Teste',
      store: 'teste',
      amount: 'R$ 5.000,00',
      sale_date: '10/10/10',
      seller: 'Alan',
      interest_rate: '0.89%',
      uf: 'MG',
      sales_network: 'LOJA 2'
    },
    {
      propose: '3',
      cpf: '000.000.000-00',
      status: 'Testando',
      store_type: 'Teste',
      store: 'teste',
      amount: 'R$ 5.000,00',
      sale_date: '10/10/10',
      seller: 'Marcos',
      interest_rate: '0.80%',
      uf: 'MG',
      sales_network: 'LOJA 1'
    },
    {
      propose: '4',
      cpf: '000.000.000-00',
      status: 'Testando',
      store_type: 'Teste',
      store: 'teste',
      amount: 'R$ 5.000,00',
      sale_date: '10/10/10',
      seller: 'Vinicius',
      interest_rate: '0.80%',
      uf: 'MG',
      sales_network: 'LOJA 1'
    },
  ];
  
  
  const UFList = data.map(item => item.uf);
  
  const uniqueUFList = [...new Set(UFList)];
  
  console.log(uniqueUFList);
```

Comment: Deu certinho! Porém, a sua solução gerou esse erro aqui no meu typescript:

Type 'Set<unknown>' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators. TS2569

Para resolver eu tive que colocar a opção "downlevelIteration": true no meu tsconfig.json no objeto de compilerOptions. Daí rodou certinho. Mas existe alguma outra solução que poderia ser aplicada para que eu não precisasse mexer no tsconfig.json?

Comment: @XXXNose adicionei um **update** na resposta sobre esse problema que você comentou.